# How do I inititialize the variable?

Tags: java

So I have a program which will print out the number of days into a year you are from a date given by the user, which includes leap years. However, when I complile the program it says the variable dayNumber is not initialized. How do I fix this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Days
{
public static void main( String [] args )
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int month, day, year;
    int dayNumber;

    System.out.print("Enter the month: ");
    month = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the day: ");
    day = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the year: ");
    year = scan.nextInt();

    if ( month == 1 )

        dayNumber = day;

    else if ( month == 2 )

        dayNumber = 31 + day;   

    else if ( month == 3 )

        if ( year % 400 == 0 )

            if ( year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 )

                dayNumber = 31 + 29 + day;


        else

            dayNumber = 31 + 28 + day;



    else if ( month == 4 )

        if ( year % 400 == 0 )

            if ( year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 )

                dayNumber = 31 + 29 + 31 + day;


        else

            dayNumber = 31 + 28 + 31 + day;



    else if ( month == 5 )

        if ( year % 400 == 0 )

            if ( year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 )

                dayNumber = 31 + 29 + 31 + 30 + day;


        else

            dayNumber = 31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + day;


    else if ( month == 6 )

        if ( year % 400 == 0 )

            if ( year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 )

                dayNumber = 31 + 29 + 31 + 30 + 31 + day;


        else

            dayNumber = 31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + day;


    else if ( month == 7 )

        if ( year % 400 == 0 )

            if ( year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 )

                dayNumber = 31 + 29 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + day;


        else

            dayNumber = 31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + day;


    else if ( month == 8 )

        if ( year % 400 == 0 )

            if ( year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 )

                dayNumber = 31 + 29 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + day;


        else

            dayNumber = 31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + day;


    else if ( month == 9 )

        if ( year % 400 == 0 )

            if ( year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 )

                dayNumber = 31 + 29 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + + 31 + day;


        else

            dayNumber = 31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + day;


    else if ( month == 10 )

        if ( year % 400 == 0 )

            if ( year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 )

                dayNumber = 31 + 29 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + + 31 + 30 + day;


        else

            dayNumber = 31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + day;


    else if ( month == 11 )

        if ( year % 400 == 0 )

            if ( year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 )

                dayNumber = 31 + 29 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + + 31 + 30 + 31 + day;


        else

            dayNumber = 31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + day;


    else 

        if ( year % 400 == 0 )

            if ( year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 )

                dayNumber = 31 + 29 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + day;


        else

            dayNumber = 31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + day;


    System.out.println("The date " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year + " is day number " + dayNumber);

}
}
```

Thank you for any help you can give!

Comment: Always use braces for your `if else`. It will avoid bugs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If by "run the program" you mean compile, you need to set dayNumber to something before all the if statements. You should not that your tabbing suggests you do not understand if/else statements entirely. For instance:

```
    if ( year % 400 == 0 )
        if ( year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 )
            dayNumber = 31 + 29 + day;
    else
        dayNumber = 31 + 28 + day;
```

The else is connected to the last if (in this case year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0). If this is not what you want then you would need:

```
    if ( year % 400 == 0 )
    {
        if ( year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 )
            dayNumber = 31 + 29 + day;
    }
    else
        dayNumber = 31 + 28 + day;
```

Which it should be noted, would not set dayNumber to anything.

Comment: And that worked perfectly, thank you a bunch. I was still a little bit confused in the beginning about what the curly brackets did but that cleared it up! And yeah, I meant compile the program not run. My mistake, I fixed it in the OP. Thank you very much and have a wonderful evening!

Comment: +1, it´s true that the root cause is the difference between intended (indented :-) ) and actual if-then-else-logic. Cool :D

Answer (score 3):

That's because the compiler detects you may have a path not initializing the variable.

**Don't do `int dayNumber=0` : this would only hide the real bug**

The solution **isn't** to initialize int `int dayNumber=0` but to check your code.

In order to be able to do so, make your code readable. I suggest you use `switch` instead of those `if` :

```
switch (month) {
case 1:
    ...
    break;
case 2:
...
```

And think a little about this part of your code :

```
else if ( month == 3 )
    if ( year % 400 == 0 )
        if ( year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 )
```

What happens to dayNumber if the first two tests are true but not the third one ?

Comment: Sadly I am unable to use switch in this assignment, but thank you anyways!

Comment: This doesn't change the real problem : you have cases leading to not assigned dayNumber.

Answer (score 0):

Simply as `int dayNumber=0;`, You also need to initialize other variables(`month, day, year`). Not exactly to 0, you can initialize it to other default values(See @dystroy's answer).

In java, If variables are local then you have to initialize them otherwise you will get complier error.

While Class fields are intialized to their default values. See [variables here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) for more info, check next `Primitive Data Types` chapter too on given link.

Comment: I tried to set it equal to zero, but then it just printed out as zero in the end instead of changing based on the month and day =/

Comment: user1645307, see my post below. You are missing several conditions. For instance March 1, 1995 will not get assigned a value because year % 400 != 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
int month, day, year;
int dayNumber;

dayNumber = month = day = year = 0;
```

It's a little overkill on my part, but at least it covers all the bases...

Comment: It's okay, each downvote also takes away from there rep as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just write:

```
int dayNumber = 0;
```

All local variables, in Java,  must be initilized before first use.

Comment: There should be a rule to check that first 3 downvotes must be provided with reasons.

Comment: Probably downvoted since it is a fix, not a solution. Assigning 0 instead of not assigning anything at all, thus just supressing the error message will probably not compute the correct result.

Comment: I agree, but i'm trying to answer the question and not solving it for OP.

Comment: @Azodious, for this to be useful, it would require the OP to know what OP does not know so OP can ask the right question. Most questions ask about symptoms, not the root cause, so I´d really recommend to find the question behind the question and answer both. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @TheBlastOne: Yes, will try to add more value to answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `int dayNumber=0;` 
You might be wondering why it is not there for `month`, `day` and `year`. This is because compiler finds that for these attibutes you are assigning values to it before they are being used. But in case of `dayNumber` you are setting values for it in conditional loops and there is chance that it may not be executed before `dayNumber` is accessed for printing.